# Is there a countdown timer app that I can use with the hardware volume buttons?

Tags: applications, hardware, buttons

I'm doing a kind of meditation that requires regularly setting a countdown timer for a few seconds, then when it stops and buzzes, starting it again. I've used a variety of apps for this, but with a touchscreen it's annoying to have to pay attention to where my finger is on the screen, just to hit the same button over and over.

It would be awesome if I could use the volume buttons on the side. I know some apps ("Stopwatch & Timer") that offer this in stopwatch mode, so it's totally doable, but I can't seem to find one that has this feature for timers. Anybody know one?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). You might wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) to find a fitting place for your question.

Comment: I think question is okay for this site. There is a specific problem to be solved here.

Comment: Let's frame it as: I have an issue with using my Android device, in that I can't seem to activate countdowns using the volume buttons, which I believe should be possible.

Comment: I totally understand not wanting questions like "what is the best app for X?" because those are opinion-based. This is a specific problem that I currently don't know how to solve, aside from developing it on my own, which I'd prefer not to.

Comment: what do you actually want to do?  Change the timer value then start it?  Just restart it?  Do you know what intervals you need beforehand?  If so then some of the exercise timer systems may do the job I have one in my Bike computer app IpBike but there are other options.

Comment: I just want to restart the timer. Like, it hits the end, vibrates, I think "did I make it to the end without getting distracted?" and if yes I restart. The reflection period is important and is why just using a looped timer isn't a good option.

I would be adjusting the interval up or down depending on how hard/easy the previous interval is...